# Searching inside list of upvoted questions and answers

Tags: support, search

Does there exist a method to search inside the list of questions and answers that you have upvoted (or downvoted)?

By list, I was referring to https://math.stackexchange.com/users/your_user_#/your_username?tab=votes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method for that, other than scraping the aforementioned list with a script, and searching the result (by title only).

There is a feature request to introduce such search method: [Search by keyword for answer / question I upvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224344/). I put a bounty on it, and also upvoted; you may want to support the proposal with an upvote.